# Why converting string dates with yyyy-mm-dd get strange results, but string dates with yyyy/mm/dd get correct ones?

Tags: javascript, string, date

In short, I have the string date 2022-04-01 (this is the startDate.value), and I need to convert it to a Date.

I have this code:

```
const startDate0Hours = new Date(new Date(startDate.value).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
console.log('this is the date (string):', startDate.value);
console.log('this is without replace:', new Date(startDate.value));
console.log('this is with replace (/-/g, "\/"):', new Date((startDate.value).replace(/-/g,'\/')));
console.log('this is with setHours(0,0,0,0):', startDate0Hours)
```

Which prints this: [screenshot][1]

```
this is the date (string): 2022-04-01
this is without replace: Thu Mar 31 2022 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)
this is with replace (/-/g, "/"): Fri Apr 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)
this is with setHours(0,0,0,0): Thu Mar 31 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)
```

Why does string date with '-' gets converted a day before, and 21h, but string date with '/' get correctly converted?

Comment: are you 3 hours from UTC? either plus or minus - oh, wait ... you are

Comment: `new Date("yyyy-mm-dd")` gets you UTC midnight - `new Date("yyyy/mm/dd")` gets you midnight local time - the clue to the time being 21:00:00 on the previous day is in your `GMT-0300` timezone

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse may be of use here

Comment: Make sure screenshot is added succesfully